# ValidationEventHandler triggered only once?

Tags: c#, .net

I have XML file, which has 2 mistakes by XSD. But ValidationEventHandler triggered only once, and shows me the second mistake only when I correct the first mistake.
this is my code:

```
       public static void ValidateXml(string xml, string xsd)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += settings_ValidationEventHandler;
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(xsd));
        if (settings.Schemas.Count > 0)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xml, settings))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                }                    
            }
        }
    }

    private static void settings_ValidationEventHandler(object sender,
                                    ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validation Error Message: {0}", e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Validation Error Severity: {0}", e.Severity);
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Validation Error Line Number: {0}",
                    e.Exception.LineNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Validation Error Line Position: {0}",
                    e.Exception.LinePosition);               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your problem. If you want your to ensure the XML is correct, it makes no different if it has 1 error or 2. Your code is letting you know the XML is not correct.

Furthermore, I suppose XmlReader won't (maybe even can't) continue reading if it finds an error.

Comment: XmlReader continues reading the current document till the end, but ignores the missed elements. I must generate a report that will show the all mistakes in the document.

Comment: Maybe you can try Validate method